# How to retrieve blank values from XML node

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML as below

```
<Element>
     <Name>srmgmtaddress</Name>
     <Value>10.133.14.19</Value>
</Element>
<Element>
     <Name>crlbif0</Name>
     <Value/>
</Element>
<Element>
     <Name>srseid.srtype</Name>
     <Value>Cisco c7206VXR</Value>
</Element>
<Element>
     <Name>craddressinterim</Name>
     <Value/>
</Element>
<Element>
     <Name>crvrfinterim</Name>
     <Value/>
</Element>
```

I want to retrieve the Element Values and I'm using the XPath expression `//ResponseItem/Object/Element/Value/text()` where ResponseItem and Object are two upper level nodes.

This works fine with the code below:

```
ArrayList<String> elementsToFetch = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("//ResponseItem/Object/Element/Name/text()","//ResponseItem/Object/Element/Value/text()"));

for (String n : elementsToFetch) {

    XPathFactory xPathfactory1 = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath1 = xPathfactory1.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr1 = xpath1.compile(n);
    NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr1.evaluate(doc1, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i=0;i<nl.getLength();i++) {
    String nodeval = nl.item(i).getNodeValue();

    //...SOME CODE HERE
    }
}
```

But I also want to retrieve the blank XML node values in "crlbif0", "craddressinterim" etc as NULL or "".

Right now I'm getting the list as below where blank nodes are not getting processed

```
[CRNdNode_RO:1024, chn-pe2-rt02, 10.133.14.19, Cisco c7206VXR, CRNdNode_RO:1037, chn-pe4-rt04, 10.133.14.6, Cisco c7609 ...]
```

I want the list as

```
[CRNdNode_RO:1024, chn-pe2-rt02, 10.133.14.19, "", Cisco c7206VXR, "", "", CRNdNode_RO:1037, chn-pe4-rt04, 10.133.14.6, "", Cisco c7609, "", "",....]
```

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried something like `//ResponseItem/Object/Element/Name/../Value/text()`? Essentially you want to find the `Name` node and take it's parent and get the `Value` sub-node off that.

Answer (score 0):

In your XPath expression, select the elements instead of the text nodes.  In your loop, call `nl.item(i).getTextContent()`.

Comment: It works for me.  The XPath expressions I'm using are: `Arrays.asList("//ResponseItem/Object/Element/Name","//ResponseItem/Object/Element/Value")`

Answer (score 0):

I just got the solution for this and thought to share the same.

I just changed the XPath expression to

```
//ResponseItem/Object/Element/Value[string-length(text())>=0]
```

This works...